# How to get values from select statement into a variable?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

I want to store the result from select statement into a variable that I can use to show in a message.

```vb
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim result As String

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Key_Old FROM Pivot_Old where Pivot_Old.Count = " & 1 & ""
   
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

result = rst!result
rst.Close

MsgBox ("String is " & result)
```

I want the result from the select statement to display in a msgbox.

Answer (score 4):

> ```vb
> result = rst!result
> ```

This notation is magical shorthand for this:

```vb
result = rst.Fields("result").Value
```

And your query doesn't have any `result` field. So either you change the query to alias `Key_Old` to `result`:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT Key_Old As result FROM Pivot_Old where Pivot_Old.Count = " & 1 & ""
...
result = rst.Fields("result").Value
```

Or, you change how you're referring to that field:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT Key_Old FROM Pivot_Old where Pivot_Old.Count = " & 1 & ""
...
result = rst.Fields("Key_Old").Value
```

Rule of thumb, prefer explicit code over magical shorthand notation =)

Comment: Hi Mat, I have changed my code as per your solution, but I am getting too few parameter error.  This is how, I have modified this time. I am really sorry. Actually I am new to this language so I don't know much.

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT Key_Old As result FROM Pivot_Old where Pivot_Old.Count = " & 1 & ""
   
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

result = rst.Fields(Key_Old).Value

rst.Close

Comment: Note that the answer shows rst.Fields() taking a string value (`"Key_Old"`) where you are passing in the field name as if it were a defined VB variable. Put in the quotes and I suspect it will work.

Comment: @RDFozz that's a rather old post, but if they just put in the quotes they'll be referring to a field named `Key_Old` from a query that aliases this column to `result` - the key part of the answer was the "either ... or" around the code blocks, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, you’re absolutely right - amazing how hard code is can be to follow when it’s buried in plain text. In the OP’s code posted above in comments on 2018-01-10, changing ‘rst.Fields(Key_Old).Value’ to ‘rst.Fields(“result”).Value’ should make things work. Added for those, like me, who came in late. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Key_Old FROM Pivot_Old where Pivot_Old.Count = " & 1 & ""

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

result = rst(0).Value
rst.Close

MsgBox ("String is " & result)
```

or keep it really simple:

```
result = Nz(DLookup("Key_Old", "Pivot_Old", "[Count] = " & 1 & ""))
MsgBox "String is " & result
```